# array to send with jquery post

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Im trying to send a array to my method with `$.post()` but Im kinda lost how to go about this.

I am getting the values of the checkboxes thats outside my form and pass them into my method.

I tried to use `.serializeArray()` & `.serialize()` but get the error that

> list.serializeArray is not a function

I i just send in the array i get null value.

HTML

```
<form....><input type="submit" value="submit" id="click_post" /></form>

<div id="container">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2,3" name="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" value="4,5" name="checkbox" />
        <input type="checkbox" value="6,7" name="checkbox" />
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('#click_post').click(function () {
                var list = new Array();
                $('#container input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
                    list.push($(this).val());
                });

                var $form = $(this).closest('form');
                $.post($form.attr('action'), { value: list }, function (data) {
                    alert('test');
                });
            });
```

METHOD

```
public ActionResult PassArray(string[] value){//doing some logic here}
```

Comment: have you tried to wrap your list in an jQuery Object ? $(list).serialize () ?

Comment: the wrap only creates a empty object for me

Comment: Maybe you could write what you expect to be sent as post data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>$('#click_post').click(function () {
        var $form = $(this).closest('form');
        $.post($form.attr('action'), $form.serialize(), function (data) {
            alert('test');
        });
    });</strike>

and also change the name of your action parameter to `checkbox` (because that's what you used as name for the checkboxes in the form):

```
public ActionResult PassArray(string[] checkbox) {
    ...    
}
```

---

UPDATE:

or if you wanted to send only the values of the checkboxes and not any other form input elements you might need to use the `traditional` mode:

```
$('#click_post').click(function () {
    var list = new Array();
    $('#container input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        list.push($(this).val());
    });

    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.ajax({
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        traditional: true,
        data: { value: list },
        success: function(result) {
            alert('test');
        }
    });
});
```

or:

```
$('#click_post').click(function () {
    var list = new Array();
    $('#container input[type="checkbox"]').each(function () {
        list.push($(this).val());
    });

    var $form = $(this).closest('form');
    $.post($form.attr('action'), $.param({ value: list }, true), function(result) {
        alert('test');
    });
});
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult PassArray(string[] value) {
    ...    
}
```

Comment: but the checkboxes are outside my form, thats the thing

Comment: that works Darin, thanks. Why does it work with $.ajax and not $.post?

Comment: @Dejan.S, because in jQuery 1.4 they changed the way parameters are serialized. They introduced the traditional parameter which allows you to fallback to the old format. But this parameter can be specified with the $.ajax method. Take a look at the documentation for further details about what exactly changed: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 0):

`serialize` or `serializeArray` should be applied to a jQuery object not a simple array, for example:

```
var serialized_data = $form.serialize();
```

Data passed to `$.post` should be:

> **data** A map or string that is sent to the server with the request.

So you should change `PassArray` method argument.

---

You can also serialize data outside a form:

```
var serialized_data = $('#container input:checkbox').serialize();
```

Comment: this does not help me, my values are outside the form

Comment: Normally, the values you post should be in the form you post

Comment: -1, Well this situation its not and sometimes you want to fetch more info from outside the form

Comment: See above how to serialize outside a form.

Comment: does no difference, you tried that yourself? i got the answer already but stil this is not valid (not for me atleast)

Comment: Yes I did it, I noticed you should also give unique names to your checkboxes.

Comment: Not really, please read the question again. your code is the same as $(list).serialize();, the value gives me a null value. what im trying to do is get the values of all the checkboxes as a array. $.ajax lets me do it they way im doing it

Answer (score 0):

```
var list = new Array(); // This simply looks ugly
var list = []; //This is the best way to so it in js - both are the same though
//everything else seems fine.. now
var data = {value: JSON.stringify(list)}; // -> '[1,2,3]' and so on
```

The rest of your code is fine. Though I wonder, why use the form when you're looping over check boxes and constructing your own data anyway? Are these check boxes within the form? Even so, does it just hold the post link for you?